# How to display value from Managed Bean in Spring integrated with JSF

Tags: spring-boot, maven-3, jsf-2.2, adminlte

I'm trying to display String value from a managed bean, but I think that the xhtml page doesn't see the bean at all as the value in the UI always empty.

Here's the code for the bean, trying to display the returned value of getMod()

```
@ManagedBean(name="user")
@SessionScoped
public class WebTest implements Serializable{

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {

    }

    ScheduleModel model = new ScheduleModel();
    public String mod = model.getName();

    public String getMod() {
            return mod;
        }
        public void setMod(String mod) {
            this.mod = mod;
        }       
    }
```

And this is the xhtml div

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
       xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">

<ui:include src="header.xhtml"/>
<body class="skin-blue">
<div class="wrapper">

    <div class="form-group">
                    <label>value="#{user.getMod}" </label>
                    <br/>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Name" />
                  </div>
```

Comment: You lack the configuration being used for the project

Comment: @XtremeBiker I added it

Comment: How do you configure spring? And JSF? We need the pom file and the spring configuration files at least.

Comment: What does ScheduleModel look like? Perhaps it doesn't have a name.

Comment: Have you tried creating ScheduleModel inside the PostConstruct?